# Why the page number does not appear in splitting post?

Tags: pagination, split

I just follow the instructions in https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-split-wordpress-posts-into-multiple-pages/#without-plugin to split a large post into several pages. However, after inserting the page breaks, when loading the post, I can only see the first page, and there are no page numbers like **Pages: 1 2 3 4** appear in the footer, why? Do I do something wrong?

My test page is at https://www.datanumen.com/file-splitter/errors/test-error-pagination/

Thank you.

Comment: Your theme probably hasn't implemented support. Did you develop the theme? If not I suggest contacting its author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thank you for your comment, I have tried to contact the author but he does not reply. So if I need to implement by myself, how to do that? Is there any document on that?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I just find the document at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have solved the issue, by adding <?php wp_link_pages(); ?> to the page template.